# make website page get news articles from feeds

Tags: php, html, database, rss, feed

I would like to start publishing some news articles from time to time. An option would be to create a new web page for every article but this sounds like it can be done easier.
For instance I noticed clear channel uses some kind of feed, like: http://www.z100.com/cc-common/news/sections/newsarticle.html?feed=104650&article=7011404
I don't know what it means and how it works but looks like a nice way to get the article from some kind of database I guess?

Does someone knows how this works, or some other way to create new articles etc, some dynamical functionality for instance to generate links to the articles and get the right article from a database for example.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is popular and pretty quick/easy to set up. Just make sure you update when new versions come out.

It's written in php and uses myqsl by default as the database. Lots of ready to use themes and plugins are available, often for free.

http://wordpress.org/

Comment: I noticed a lot of blogs use wordpress. I do not wish to create a blog but just news articles from time to time. Also I prefer HTML as I have little experience with PHP and all my pages yet are in HTML. Can wordpress still work in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think a blog is, but if you post any type of articles from time to time, that is, by definition, a blog. It's a very general purpose term for posting multiple entries over time. And the output is all in html. (PHP is executed on the server, and sends the output to the browser - if you "view source" you will never see php, only html)

Comment: Okay, My understanding was a webpage dedicated to posting messages is a blog. I don't wish to have 1 page with all my entries on it, but more something like a news network. Visitors should be able to see headlines, click on it and a page should open with just that news article on it.
So I could have some php code on my existing .html page which retrieves the desired article from the database (excuted by php) and show up in the .html page?

Comment: You keep describing a blog. Just show headlines on the main page if that's what you want. It takes less time to install wordpress or some other open source CMS than you have spent asking this question. Just install one and play with it for a minute and you will find out that you are making this way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: installed it a week ago, works okay, just need to discover how the php code works but I guess there are plenty of 'how-to's' on the net about it.
and if nothing I can always ask around here.

Answer (score 0):

Its the basic functionality of any [content management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems).

Essentially it boils down to:

1. Extract identifier from URI
2. Look up data associated with that identifier in a database
3. Insert that data into a template

Comment: And where can I find such a CMS?

Comment: So what's an easy and simple CMS, I need basic functionality just for news articles.